# Alloy UI - Get Record After Updated

Tags: javascript, alloy-ui

In Alloy UI, how can I execute a function on my Data Table after modifying the data with a [TextCellEditor](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.BaseCellEditor.html)?

```
fieldEditor.on(
    'save', 
    function(e) { 
        //do something
});
```

Once the TextCellEditor is saved, the table would pickup the changes from that same row.

```
dataTable.after(
    'recordChanged',
    function(e) { 
        //get Record Changed
});
```

Comment: What are you using the record for? If you want the new value (or old value) of the record, you can use the `newVal` or (`prevVal`) data from the `event`

Comment: The new and prev Values are good but I need the entire record with the new value included. Right now I'm just trying to save that record/object to a variable

Answer (score 0):

I am able to trigger my event by using the wildcard on the event listener, like so:

```
dataTable.after(
    '*:change',
    function(e) { 
        //get Record Changed
});
```

However I am unaware what else might trigger this event since it seems to encompass all dataTable changes. What I am going for is `record:change` but that doesn't appear to be working